# What does this pair of brackets around "(BluetoothManager)" do?

Tags: java, android

```
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
        (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
```

Doing a little research I found out that "BluetoothManager" is a class, but the ret val of method "getSystemService" is a string. Is this an attempt to forcefully convert a string into a class? If it is not, what is it then?

Comment: getSystemService returns an Object not a String

Comment: In US English and consequently programming English, these are brackets: `[ ]`  Those things in your question are *parentheses*.  The searchable term for how they're being used here is **casting**.

Comment: Wow you have no idea how embarrassed I am right now I knew they were parentheses but some how "brackets" got stuck. JC what happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

Quot from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

final < T> getSystemService(Class< T> serviceClass)
Return the handle to a system-level service by class.

I am not sure where did you get "but the ret val of method "getSystemService" is a string.". But It appears that what you found is wrong.